# Cookie not sent over SSL in apache server

Tags: php, apache, cookies, server, session-cookies

I'm running apache version 2.4.57 windows server with PHP version 8.

I'm encountering an issue where cookies are not being sent over SSL (HTTPS). I have a web application that uses HTTPS, but for some reason, the cookies are not being included in the request headers.

I have tried this

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
```

in apache httpd.conf file.

kindly help me to fix this. Please go with below attached screenshot for more Clarence.

[image]

I already set this in my apache configuration file using PHP codingter4 framework enable to fix this from my end after lots of effort please help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.